# What does |= (ior) do in Python?

Tags: python

Google won't let me search `|=` so I'm having trouble finding relevant documentation. Anybody know?

Comment: I think it's relevant to point out, as in sunny's answer below, that `|` is also used as the set union operator

Answer (score 236, accepted):

`|=` performs an *[in-place](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#in-place-operators)*<sup>+</sup> operation between pairs of objects.  In particular, between:

- [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html): a [union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)) operation
- [dicts](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#dict): an [update](https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/3.9.html#dictionary-merge-update-operators) operation
- [counters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter): a [union (of multisets)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Basic_properties_and_operations) operation
- [numbers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html): a [bitwise OR](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations), binary operation

In most cases, it is related to the `|` operator.  See examples below.

**Sets**

For example, the union of two sets assigned to `s1` and `s2` share the following equivalent expressions:

```
>>> s1 = s1 | s2                                           # 1
>>> s1 |= s2                                               # 2
>>> s1.__ior__(s2)                                         # 3
```

where the final value of `s1` is equivalent either by:

1. an assigned OR operation
2. an in-place OR operation
3. an in-place OR operation via special method<sup>++</sup>

*Example*

Here we apply OR (`|`) and the in-place OR (`|=`) to *sets*:

```
>>> s1 = {"a", "b", "c"}
>>> s2 = {"d", "e", "f"}

>>> # OR, | 
>>> s1 | s2
{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'}
>>> s1                                                     # `s1` is unchanged
{'a', 'b', 'c'}

>>> # In-place OR, |=
>>> s1 |= s2
>>> s1                                                     # `s1` is reassigned
{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'}
```

---

**Dictionaries**

In [Python 3.9+](https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/3.9.html#dictionary-merge-update-operators), new merge (`|`) and update (`|=`) operators are proposed between dictionaries. Note: these are not the same as set operators mentioned above.

Given operations between two dicts assigned to `d1` and `d2`:

```
>>> d1 = d1 | d2                                           # 1
>>> d1 |= d2                                               # 2
```

where `d1` is equivalent via:

1. an assigned merge-right operation
2. an in-place merge-right (update) operation; equivalent to `d1.update(d2)`

*Example*

Here we apply merge (`|`) and update (`|=`) to *dicts*:

```
>>> d1 = {"a": 0, "b": 1, "c": 2}
>>> d2 = {"c": 20, "d": 30}

>>> # Merge, | 
>>> d1 | d2
{"a": 0, "b": 1, "c": 20, "d": 30}
>>> d1 
{"a": 0, "b": 1, "c": 2}

>>> # Update, |=
>>> d1 |= d2
>>> d1 
{"a": 0, "b": 1, "c": 20, "d": 30}
```

---

**Counters**

The `collections.Counter` is related to a mathematical datastructure called a [*multiset*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) (mset).  It is basically a dict of (object, multiplicity) key-value pairs.

Given operations between two counters assigned to `c1` and `c2`:

```
>>> c1 = c1 | c2                                           # 1
>>> c1 |= c2                                               # 2
```

where `c1` is equivalent via:

1. an assigned union operation
2. an in-place union operation

A [union of multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Basic_properties_and_operations) contains the maximum multiplicities per entry.  Note, this does not behave the same way as between two sets or between two regular dicts.

*Example*

Here we apply union (`|`) and the in-place union (`|=`) to *Counters*:

```
import collections as ct


>>> c1 = ct.Counter({2: 2, 3: 3})
>>> c2 = ct.Counter({1: 1, 3: 5})

>>> # Union, |    
>>> c1 | c2
Counter({2: 2, 3: 5, 1: 1})
>>> c1
Counter({2: 2, 3: 3})

>>> # In-place Union, |=
>>> c1 |= c2
>>> c1
Counter({2: 2, 3: 5, 1: 1})
```

---

**Numbers**

Lastly, you can do binary math.

Given operations between two numbers assigned to `n1` and `n2`:

```
>>> n1 = n1 | n2                                           # 1
>>> n1 |= n2                                               # 2
```

where `n1` is equivalent via:

1. an assigned bitwise OR operation
2. an in-place bitwise OR operation

*Example*

Here we apply bitwise OR (`|`) and the in-place bitwise OR (`|=`) to *numbers*:

```
>>> n1 = 0
>>> n2 = 1

>>> # Bitwise OR, |
>>> n1 | n2
1
>>> n1
0

>>> # In-place Bitwise OR, |=
>>> n1 |= n2
>>> n1
1
```

---

**Review**

This section briefly reviews some bitwise math.  In the simplest case, the bitwise OR operation compares two binary bits.  It will always return `1` except when both bits are `0`.

```
>>> assert 1 == (1 | 1) == (1 | 0) == (0 | 1)
>>> assert 0 == (0 | 0)
```

We now extend this idea beyond binary numbers.  Given any two integral numbers (lacking fractional components), we apply the bitwise OR and get an integral result:

```
>>> a = 10 
>>> b = 16 
>>> a | b
26
```

How?  In general, the bitwise operations follow some "rules":

1. internally compare binary equivalents
2. apply the operation
3. return the result as the given type

Let's apply these rules to our regular integers above.

(1) Compare binary equivalents, seen here as strings (`0b` denotes binary):

```
>>> bin(a)
'0b1010'
>>> bin(b)
'0b10000'
```

(2) Apply a bitwise OR operation to each column (`0` when both are `0`, else `1`):

```
01010
10000
-----
11010
```

(3) Return the result in the given type, e.g. base 10, decimal:

```
>>> int(0b11010)
26
```

The internal binary comparison means we can apply the latter to integers in any base, e.g. hex and octal:

```py
>>> a = 10                                   # 10, dec
>>> b = 0b10000                              # 16, bin
>>> c = 0xa                                  # 10, hex
>>> d = 0o20                                 # 16, oct

>>> a | b
26
>>> c | d
26
```

**See Also**

- An example of [overloading the `__ior__()` method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5ce0a2a100909104836f53a2c8823006ec46f8ad/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L604) to iterate iterables in a `MutableSet` abstract base class
- R. Hettinger's [OrderedSet recipe (see lines 3 and 10 respectively)](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694-orderedset/)
- A [thread on Python-ideas](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2018-March/049233.html) on why to use `|=` to update a set
- A [section B.8 of Dive in Python 3](http://www.diveintopython3.net/special-method-names.html) on special methods of Python operators
- In-place binary operators fallback to regular methods, see cpython source code ([eval.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b1a94f1fab7c0aee0705483616a1b2c3f2713c00/Python/ceval.c#L2353) and [abstract.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b1a94f1fab7c0aee0705483616a1b2c3f2713c00/Objects/abstract.c#L1239)).  Thanks @asottile.
- A [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74844719/does-a-bitwise-and-operation-prepend-zeros-to-the-binary-representation) on how python handles displaying prepended zeros in bitwise computations

<sup>+</sup><sub>The in-place bitwise OR operator cannot be applied to literals; assign objects to names.</sub>

<sup>++</sup><sub>Special methods return the same operations as their corresponding operators.</sub>

Comment: To be perfectly clear, I would add to the demonstration that after doing the regular assignation (x = x | y) the id(x) has changed because it's a new object, while |= keeps the same id because it's the original x that is modified, hence the name "inplace".

Comment: In the numbers section, you are claiming that second statement does in-place operation. I think it is not true, since `int`s are not mutable in Python.

Comment: how come `a=1, a |= 2` works even thought int doesn't have __ior__ method? It there a way to override `|=` when subclassing int ?

Comment: @Kazz According to the datamodel docs, assignment falls back to a normal method, e.g. (`__or__()`, `__ror__()`).  You can try overriding the first.

Answer (score 114):

In Python, and many other programming languages, `|` is the [bitwise-OR operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation). `|=` is to `|` as `+=` is to `+`, i.e. a combination of operation and asignment.

So `var |= value` is short for `var = var | value`.

A common use case is to merge two sets:

```py
>>> a = {1,2}; a |= {3,4}; print(a)
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: Have given one use case I encountered below

Answer (score 53):

When used with sets it performs union operation.

Comment: I was reading some code and the `|=` was used in set context, and it wasn't until I messed around and figured it out that I noticed this answer was here too

Answer (score 49):

This is just an OR operation between the current variable and the other one. Being `T=True` and `F=False`, see the output graphically:

| r | s | `r|=s` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T | T | T |
| T | F | T |
| F | T | T |
| F | F | F |

For example:

```
>>> r=True
>>> r|=False
>>> r
True
>>> r=False
>>> r|=False
>>> r
False
>>> r|=True
>>> r
True
```

Comment: This gives a kinda of warped impression of the operator; `|` is a bitwise-or operator for integers, not specifically a boolean operator, and for anything other than `bool`s, it won't actually produce `True` or `False` outputs. `bool` is a subclass of `int`, and to be nice, they overloaded it for `bool` to keep producing `True`/`False` outputs, but in most cases, boolean operations should be done with `or`, not `|`. Normal uses for `|` are bitwise-or, or set-union. Better examples of use would be something like `a = 0b1001; a |= 0b0010; print(bin(a))` which produces `0b1011`.

Answer (score 10):

It performs a binary bitwise OR of the left-hand and right-hand sides of the assignment, then stores the result in the left-hand variable.

http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations

Answer (score 4):

It's bitwise or.
Let's say we have `32 | 10`, picture 32 and 10 in binary:

```
32 = 10 0000
10 = 00 1010
```

Now because `|` is the OR operation, do a bitwise-or on the two numbers

i.e 1  or 0 -->  1, 0 or 0 --> 0. Continue this down the chain:

```
10 0000 | 00 1010 = 10 1010.
```

Now change the binary into a decimal, `10 1010 = 42`.

For `|=`, think of the known examples, `x +=5`. It means `x = x + 5,` therefore if we have `x |= 5`, it means `x = x bitwiseor with 5`.

Comment: this is the explanation I was looking for, everyone talked about sets and bools but no one mentioned its use with numbers.

Comment: The example you gave is not  `32 |= 10` but rather `32 | 10`. Just to clarify this for future readers :)

Comment: @sniper71 what is the result of 32 |= 10

Comment: `32 |= 10` is a syntax error, because `32` is not a valid assignment target.

Answer (score 2):

In Python,|=(ior) works like union operation.
like if x=5 and x|=5 then both the value will first convert in binary value then the union operation will perform and we get the answer 5.

Answer (score 2):

To give a use-case (after spending time with the other answers):

```
def process(item):
   return bool(item) # imagine some sort of complex processing taking place above

def any_success(data): # return True if at least one is successful
    at_least_one = False
    for item in data:
       at_least_one |= process(item)
    return at_least_one

>>> any_success([False, False, False])
False
>>> any_success([True, False, False])
True
>>> any_success([False, True, False])
True
```

Basically `any` without the short-circuiting: might be useful if you need to process every item and record at least one success etc.

See also the caveats in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929433/does-python-have-an-or-equals-function-like-in-ruby)

Answer (score 2):

***It means bitwise OR operation.***

Example :

```
x = 5
x |= 3 #which is similar to x = x | 3
print(x)
```

***Answer : 7***

**How does it works?**

```
The binary of 5 is : 0 1 0 1
The binary of 3 is : 0 0 1 1

OR operation : (If one of both sides are 1/True then result is 1/True)

0 1 0 1  #Binary of 5
0 0 1 1  #Binary of 3
---------------------
0 1 1 1  #Binary of 7
```

***So, the answer is 7***

Answer (score 2):

`|` is bitwise OR. So `x |= y` is equivalent* to `x = x | y`.

For sets, `|` takes on a related meaning: set unions. The same way you would take the intersection of 2 sets in math using OR, you can do it in python using `|`

*Note: The 2 expressions are not 100% equivalent. After `x |= y`, `id(x) == id(y)`. After `x = x | y`, `id(x) != id(y)`

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this also helps others to understand:

```
dict1 = {'a': 'dict1', 'b': 'dict1', 'c': 'dict1'}
dict2 = {'c': 'dict2', 'd': 'dict2', 'e': 'dict2'}

dict3 = dict1.copy()
dict3 = dict3 | dict2
dict4 = dict1.copy()
dict4 |= dict2
print(f'dict1:\n {dict1}')
print(f'dict2:\n {dict2}')
print(f'dict1 after dict1 = dict1 | dict2 (dict2 index c replaces dict1 index c, items in dict1 are discarded if present in dict2):\n {dict3}')
print(f'dict1 after dict1 |= dict2 (same behaviour as dict1 = dict1 | dict2):\n {dict4}')

dict5 = dict1.copy()
dict5 = dict2 | dict5
dict6 = dict2.copy()
dict6 |= dict1
print(f'dict1 after dict1 = dict2 | dict1 (dict2 index c is missing, dict1 index c was retained, items in dict2 are discarded if present in dict1):\n {dict5}')
print(f'dict2 after dict2 |= dict1 (same behaviour as dict2 = dict2 | dict1):\n {dict6}')


dict1:
 {'a': 'dict1', 'b': 'dict1', 'c': 'dict1'}
dict2:
 {'c': 'dict2', 'd': 'dict2', 'e': 'dict2'}
dict1 after dict1 = dict1 | dict2 (dict2 index c replaces dict1 index c, items in dict1 are discarded if present in dict2):
 {'a': 'dict1', 'b': 'dict1', 'c': 'dict2', 'd': 'dict2', 'e': 'dict2'}
dict1 after dict1 |= dict2 (same behaviour as dict1 = dict1 | dict2):
 {'a': 'dict1', 'b': 'dict1', 'c': 'dict2', 'd': 'dict2', 'e': 'dict2'}
dict1 after dict1 = dict2 | dict1 (dict2 index c is missing, dict1 index c was retained, items in dict2 are discarded if present in dict1):
 {'c': 'dict1', 'd': 'dict2', 'e': 'dict2', 'a': 'dict1', 'b': 'dict1'}
dict2 after dict2 |= dict1 (same behaviour as dict2 = dict2 | dict1):
 {'c': 'dict1', 'd': 'dict2', 'e': 'dict2', 'a': 'dict1', 'b': 'dict1'}
```