# Does Python have an "or equals" function like ||= in Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby

If not, what is the best way to do this?

Right now I'm doing (for a django project):

```
if not 'thing_for_purpose' in request.session:
    request.session['thing_for_purpose'] = 5
```

but its pretty awkward. In Ruby it would be:

```
request.session['thing_for_purpose'] ||= 5
```

which is much nicer.

Comment: Note that these two bits of code are actually very different: the Python version sets it to 5 if it's not in the dict at all, where the Ruby version also sets it to 5 if it's set to any false value.

Comment: @Glenn, not _very_ different, but quite different. Since an uninitialized hash value returns `nil` (false in boolean context) this idiom is often used exactly for the purpose sean has used it. The idiom only works though if, of course, `nil` and `false` are not legitimate values in the hash (which is very often true, so the idiom is fine)

Comment: @banister: I don't know where one might draw the line between "very" and "quite", but the point is these aren't equivalent statements, and it's important to understand the difference.  (False is very often a valid value in a hash, which will bite you when you want to set a default for a boolean field to true; it's a significant shortcoming of Ruby's idiom.)

Comment: Yes the Python example is more akin to *defined-or*, like `//=` which you find in [perl](http://search.cpan.org/~rgarcia/perl-5.10.0-RC2/pod/perl5100delta.pod#Defined-or_operator).  I think the `||=` also originates from Perl.

Comment: Ah good points, all. I hadn't noticed this difference.

Answer (score 227, accepted):

Jon-Eric's answer's is good for dicts, but the title seeks a general equivalent to [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby)'s `||=` operator.

A common way to do something like `||=` in Python is

```
x = x or new_value
```

Comment: This answer is likely what the folks coming here from a Google search are looking for.

Comment: Note that unlike in Ruby, this code will only work if `x` has been previously defined (for example set to `None` in a class initialization method).

Comment: True, this doesn't behave exactly like Ruby's ||=. Another thing to watch out for is the 'truthiness' of x. If x==0 in Python, you'll get new_value since 0 is considered false, but in Ruby you'll get 0.

Comment: Is this as efficient as ||=? ||= doesn't do an assignment unless its null, but this always does an assignment. Is the python compiler is cleverer than I think it is?

Comment: this DOESN'T work with the specific question the OP asked.  ``x = request.session['thing_for_purpose'] or 'my default'`` will raise a KeyError if 'thing_for_purpose' is not defined in the dict.   The other answers in this thread with "get" on a dict are IMHO better answers

Comment: You also cannot return the expression ||= like you can in ruby; you'd have to follow that with `return x` if you are trying to (for instance) lazy load an instance variable

Comment: Is it only me or isn't it weird that the result of this is not a boolean, but the value of either side?

Answer (score 26):

**Precise answer: No.**  Python does not have a single built-in operator `op` that can translate `x = x or y` into `x op y`.

**But, it almost does.**  The bitwise or-equals operator (`|=`) *will* function as described above if both operands are being treated as booleans, with a caveat. (What's the caveat? Answer is below of course.)

First, the basic demonstration of functionality:

```
x = True
x    
Out[141]: True

x |= True
x    
Out[142]: True

x |= False
x    
Out[143]: True

x &= False
x    
Out[144]: False

x &= True
x    
Out[145]: False

x |= False
x    
Out[146]: False

x |= True
x   
Out[147]: True
```

The caveat is due python not being strictly-typed, and thus even if the values are being treated as booleans in an expression they will not be short-circuited if given to a bitwise operator.  For example, suppose we had a boolean function which clears a list and returns `True` iff there were elements deleted:

```
def  my_clear_list(lst):
    if not lst:
        return False
    else:
        del lst[:]
        return True
```

Now we can see the short-circuited behavior as so:

```
x = True
lst = [1, 2, 3]
x = x or my_clear_list(lst)
print(x, lst)

Output: True [1, 2, 3]
```

However, switching the `or` to a bitwise or (`|`) removes the short-circuit, so the function `my_clear_list` executes.

```
x = True
lst = [1, 2, 3]
x = x | my_clear_list(lst)
print(x, lst)

Output: True []
```

Above, `x = x | my_clear_list(lst)` is equivalent to `x |= my_clear_list(lst)`.

Answer (score 20):

`dict` has [`setdefault()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault).

So if `request.session` is a `dict`:

```
request.session.setdefault('thing_for_purpose', 5)
```

Comment: Vaguely similar but in no way the equivalent of Ruby's ||=.

Comment: It's significantly different in that the default expression is evaluated even if the key is already set.

There is no way to solve the original question without either evaluating the default value, or accessing the key more than once, or both.

Answer (score 10):

Setting a default makes sense if you're doing it in a middleware or something, but if you need a default value in the context of one request:

```
request.session.get('thing_for_purpose', 5) # gets a default
```

bonus: here's how to really do an `||=` in Python.

```
def test_function(self, d=None):
    'a simple test function'
    d = d or {}

    # ... do things with d and return ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can use `dict[key] = dict.get(key, 0) + val`.