# Python's equivalent of Ruby's ||=

Tags: python, ruby

To check if a variable exist, and if exits, use the original value, other wise, use the new value assigned. 
In ruby, it's
`var ||= var_new`

How to write it in python?

PS:
I don't know the `name` of `||=`, I simply can't search it in Bing.

Comment: There is not a great perfect parallel construction to that. `try` `except` is probably the closest.

Comment: So at the point you use this syntax in Ruby, you don't know if `var` has actually been defined in the current scope? That's something that you would generally try pretty hard to avoid in Python. Or is it just that `var` is null, like `None` in Python?

Comment: I'm much more of a Rubyist than a Pythonista, but I think Python has some memoization decorators that are relevant to this discussion...

Comment: If the goal is just to make sure that after passing through a block of code that could (but not necessarily will) write to a variable, the more standard Python formulation would be to set it to the default value before entering the block; if it's not modified, it retains the original value. Not sure if your code has some special needs that this won't work for.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929433/does-python-have-an-or-equals-function-like-in-ruby but I like the answers here better 

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think there is some confusion from the people who aren't really sure what the conditional assignment operator (`||=`) does, and also some misunderstanding about how variables are spawned in Ruby.

Everyone should read [this article](http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html) on the subject. A TLDR quote:

> A common misconception is that a ||= b is equivalent to a = a || b, but it behaves like a || a = b
>
> In a = a || b, a is set to something by the statement on every run, whereas with a || a = b, a is only set if a is logically false (i.e. if it's nil or false) because || is 'short circuiting'. That is, if the left hand side of the || comparison is true, there's no need to check the right hand side.

And another very important note:

> ...a variable assignment, even if not run, immediately summons that variable into being.

```
# Ruby
x = 10 if 2 == 5
puts x
```

> Even though the first line won't be run, x will exist on the second line and no exception will be raised.

This means that Ruby will absolutely *ensure* that there is a variable container for a value to be placed into before any righthand conditionals take place. `||=` doesn't assign if `a` is *not defined*, it assigns if `a` is falsy (again, `false` or `nil` - `nil` being the default *nothingness* value in Ruby), whilst guaranteeing `a` *is* defined.

#### What does this mean for Python?

Well, if `a` is defined, the following:

```
# Ruby
a ||= 10
```

is actually equivalent to:

```
# Python
if not a:
    a = 10
```

while the following:

```
# Either language
a = a or 10
```

is close, but it *always* assigns a value, whereas the previous examples do not.

And if `a` is not defined the whole operation is closer to:

```
# Python
a = None
if not a:
    a = 10
```

Because a very explicit example of what `a ||= 10` does when `a` is not defined would be:

```
# Ruby
if not defined? a
    a = nil
end

if not a
    a = 10
end
```

At the end of the day, the `||=` operator is not *completely* translatable to Python in any kind of 'Pythonic' way, because of how it relies on the underlying variable spawning in Ruby.

Comment: After `a=None; if not a: a=10` then a is guaranteed to be 10, no? Might as well just have `a=10`

Comment: @dawg Simply showing _explicitly_ how it would look in Python, in relation to the way it just _is_ in Ruby.

Comment: I've made some edits, hope this clarifies things a bit.

Comment: I used to do `if not 'var' in globals():`, now its get a little bit short.

Comment: It sounds like the explanation of what `||=` does in the original question is wrong.  Could someone more familiar with ruby edit the question to correctly state the behaviour of that operator?

Comment: One annoyance to note is that pylint will complain that you're using a variable before its declaration even with the example: `if not var_name:`. Edit: nevermind it seems to be my scoping, using it in a function but having it defined outside (which is bad to start with, but I wanted to cache a variable/lookup)

Answer (score 5):

There is no particularly elegant way in python, because it's not particularly elegant to get yourself into a situation where you don't know whether a variable is existing or not.  However, this seems closest:

```py
try:
    var
except NameError:
    var = var_new
```

I'm not familiar with the `||=` operator in ruby, but from what you have described this block should have the correct behaviour.  That is, we leave `var` bound as is if it was an already existing variable, and we set it to `var_new` otherwise.

Comment: I'd use `_ = var` so you don't get spurious output on the console.

Comment: @MarkRansom you wouldn't get console output for this, unless you were running in the REPL

Answer (score 4):

This is approximately, and idiomatically, what you want:

```
var = var or var_new
```

Python's rules for variables that "don't exist" are quite strict; this will throw an exception if `var` has not been previously assigned.  However, if `var` *evaluates as falsey*, it will receive the value of `var_new`.

I say this is "idiomatically what you want" because the idiomatic *larger structure* for this kind of thing, in Python, goes like so:

```
var1 = None
var2 = None
var3 = None

# ... code here that may or may not set var1 through var3 ...

var1 = var1 or "default1"
var2 = var2 or "default2"
var3 = var3 or "default3"
```

Note also that Python has a fairly broad notion of "falsey".  This construct is only valid if `var` cannot have been assigned zero, False,  or any object considered to be "empty" (e.g. `""`, `[]`, `{}`...).  If you really want it to trigger only on None you have to write the more verbose

```
var = var if var is not None else var_new
```

and, rather than do that, I would generally look for another way to solve the larger problem.

Finally, if you *can* structure your code like this instead...

```
var1 = "default1"
var2 = "default2"
var3 = "default3"

# ... code here that may or may not set var1 through var3 ...
```

... then you *should*, because it's shorter and less complicated that way, and the None vs falsey issue is completely avoided.

Comment: In Python `a=a or 10` still produces a NameError if `a` does not exist. In Ruby, `a||=10` creates the name `a` and if it does not exist and assigns 10 to it.

Comment: @dawg Yes, and I do not believe that what I wrote implies otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Not very safe however another option would be:

```
var = locals().get('var', var_new)
```

Comment: it's closest probably, but you'd probably need to check in `globals()` too to have a full solution...

Comment: @CorleyBrigman there might have both a local and a global variable with the same name, so I covered only local scope.

Comment: I have barely used Python-dictionaries and have never used locals() or globals()  before, but it seems like `var = locals().get('var') if 'var' in locals().keys() else globals().get('var',var_new)` would handle both of those. ​

Answer (score 1):

```
try: var
except NameError: var = var_new
```

or

```
var = locals().get('var', var_new)
```