# Does a bitwise "and" operation prepend zeros to the binary representation?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, cpython

When I use bitwise and operator(`&`) with the number of 1 to find out if a number x is odd or even `(x & 1)`, does the interpreter change the binary representation of 1 according to the binary representation of x? For example:

- 2 & 1 -> 10 & 01 -> then perform comparison bitwise
- 5 & 1 -> 101 & 001 -> then perform comparison bitwise
- 100 & 1 -> 1100100 & 0000001 -> then perform comparison bitwise

Does it append zeros to the binary representation of 1 to perform bitwise and operation?

Looking at the [cpython implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/532aa4e4e019812d0388920768ede7c04232ebe1/Objects/longobject.c#L5266), it looks like that it compares the digits according to size of the right argument. So in this case the example above works actually:

- 2 & 1 -> 10 & 1 -> 0 & 1 -> then perform comparison bitwise
- 5 & 1 -> 101 & 1 -> 1 & 1 -> then perform comparison bitwise
- 100 & 1 -> 1100100 & 1 -> 0 & 1 -> then perform comparison bitwise

Is my understanding right? I'm confused because of [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJdPv.png) from [Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-number-is-odd-or-even-using-bitwise-operators/).

Comment: This is a bit like asking if you have to add more zeroes to the number 1 when you do 234 + 1, to make it 234 + 001, when you do arithmetic on paper. The answer is that you can pretend those zeroes are there if it makes you feel better, but they don't have to be there for the operation to make sense; the way you write the number is not the same as the number itself.

Comment: `1` is the same as `0000001` in binary, leading zeros don't alter the actual value the binary bits represent. So the cython computation you are showing are not exactly the way you describe `5 & 1 -> 101 & 1 -> 1 & 1`. This is instead `5 & 1 -> 101 & 001 -> 001 -> 1`. but its the same thing

Comment: thanks for your answer @kaya3. What do you mean with "the way you write the number is not the same as the number itself." ?

Comment: The sequence of digits "1" is different to the sequence of digits "001", but the number those two sequences of digits represent is the same number, even though they are different ways of writing it. So the sequence of digits is a different thing to the number itself, conceptually.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal but what does that part of the cython computation I am showing do? And where does it append zeros to the 1?

Comment: It doesn't append anything and that's the point. Both computations are the same, but you can better read these out with the leading zeros to understand how its working.

Comment: It might be helpful to stop and think about what the world would be like if the numbers _didn't_ work this way. You don't want `100 + 1` to be `200`, so it's necessary for numbers to be treated the same as if they were zero-padded. That doesn't mean you're changing `1` into `001`, it just means that `1` is `1`, not `100`, no matter what the other operands in use with it are.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal  I see, so the image on the website is just for intuition. It doesn't actually show the computation logic of cpython?

Comment: @kry23, right, cpython is using the CPU's built-in arithmetic hardware; other than when one gets into large integers or other content the CPU doesn't natively handle, it doesn't do anything that's local, special, or otherwise Python-specific; and even when we _are_ into large integers, they're still processed with (a larger number of) native CPU operations.

Comment: correct. algorithmically speaking they are the same thing. computationally speaking, you can avoid adding leading zeros and just use the min number of bits among the 2 numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Conceptually, adding zeros to the shorter number gives the same result as ignoring excess digits in the longer number. They both do the same thing. Padding, however, is inefficient, so in practice you wouldn't want to do it.

The reason is because anything ANDed with 0 is 0. If you pad the short number to match the longer one and then AND the extra bits they're all going to result in 0. It works, but since you know the padded bits will just result in extra zeros, it's more efficient to ignore them and only iterate over the length of the shorter number.

Python only processes the overlapping digits. First, it [conditionally swaps `a` and `b`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/532aa4e4e019812d0388920768ede7c04232ebe1/Objects/longobject.c#L5224) to ensure `b` is the smaller number:

```c
/* Swap a and b if necessary to ensure size_a >= size_b. */
if (size_a < size_b) {
    z = a; a = b; b = z;
    size_z = size_a; size_a = size_b; size_b = size_z;
    negz = nega; nega = negb; negb = negz;
}
```

Then it iterates over the smaller `size_b`:

```c
/* Compute digits for overlap of a and b. */
switch(op) {
case '&':
    for (i = 0; i < size_b; ++i)
        z->ob_digit[i] = a->ob_digit[i] & b->ob_digit[i];
    break;
```

> So my understanding is right, the image is just for intuition?

Yep, correct. The image is for conceptual understanding. It doesn't reflect how it's actually implemented in code.

Comment: Would be good to explain Python's "digits".